# 400 Bad Request with Foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

I am posting a checkin to 4sq but keep getting 400 Bad Request. Here is a very simple code that does the checkin:

```
client = new WebClient();
client.UploadStringCompleted += (s, args) =>
{
    var result = args.Result;
};
client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add/?oauth_token=my_token"),
"POST", "venueId=venue_id");
```

I am sure my_token and venue_id is correct because I use them for getting list of previous checkins and venue information.

Do you see something wrong with this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the oauth_token as a POST param, not part of the URL path.

Comment: Thanks akdotcom. oauth_token has to be in request url as per the documentation. Also putting it as a POST parameter didn't change anything.

Comment: Not sure why it didn't change anything, perhaps you have another issue, but I assure you that it's supposed to be a POST param. It's my job to know this =). Also as Matthew mentioned, you need to specify the broadcast parameter. Also, also, you shouldn't have that trailing "/" at the end of your path.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but isn't the broadcast parameter optional? I need to make sure because I'm stuck on a 400 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the 'broadcast' parameter. It's listed as required:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add.html

Comment: in fact you don't even need a venue_id, broadcast is the only required parameter. I would suggest passing a ll though if possible.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't required when I first coded this. However, it still gives me a 404.

Comment: can you post the exact call you're making (without your oauth token)? You sure you're doing a POST and not a GET?

Comment: The code above is the actual code I use. I just changed oauth_token and venue id before posting.

Comment: Is this client-side javascript?